# How to skip Weekend (Sat & Sun) from whole month calendar

Tags: java, calendar, weekday

Trying to skip weekend days from month calendar

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
for (int i = 0; i < dayOfMonth; i++) {
    id("prevDayTrackButton").click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: You want this `id("prevDayTrackButton").click();` to happen only in weekdays right?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

```
int dayOfWeek = cal.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
boolean isWeekday = ((dayOfWeek >= Calendar.MONDAY) && (dayOfWeek <= Calendar.FRIDAY));
```

`isWeekday` will be `false` if the day of the week is `Saturday` or `Sunday`.

Comment: @GirisH: If my answer solves your problem, then you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
boolean isWeekend;
if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY || 
      cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
     isWeekend = true;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the answer, instead of just providing the code

Comment: need to skip Saturday and Sunday from a whole month calendar so my script only calls from Mon - Friday

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Wallis"));
    for (LocalDate d = today.withDayOfMonth(1); d.isBefore(today); d = d.plusDays(1)) {
        DayOfWeek dow = d.getDayOfWeek();
        if (! dow.equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) && ! dow.equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)) {
            id("prevDayTrackButton").click();
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

If you fancy using a stream operation:

```
    today.withDayOfMonth(1)
            .datesUntil(today)
            .filter(d -> ! d.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY)
                            && ! d.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))
            .forEach(d -> {
                id("prevDayTrackButton").click();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            });
```

I don’t think it buys us anything in this case, though.

The `Calendar` class that you used is long outdated and poorly designed. Instead I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

```
    LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 4, 13);//LocalDate.parse("2019-04-13");
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = myDate.getDayOfWeek();
    int dayOfWeekIntValue = dayOfWeek.getValue();
    System.out.println(dayOfWeekIntValue);
    String dayOfWeekName = dayOfWeek.name();
    System.out.println(dayOfWeekName);
    boolean isWeekday = (dayOfWeekIntValue >= 1 && dayOfWeekIntValue <= 5);//Day is between MONDAY and FRIDAY, return true
    System.out.println(isWeekday);
```

Instead of old `Date` class use `LocalDate`.